# MS Teams carousel with thumbnail cards not displaying

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to get a list of cards displayed as a carousel on MS Teams with my Bot Framework empowered bot.
The carousel is displayed properly on Web Chat and on the emulator, just not on Teams. Nothing is displayed at all. The method in which the code is implemented is being called, and everything else works perfect.

Code:

```
var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            foreach (Models.Cars car in cars)
            {
                Attachment att = new Attachment();
                List<CardAction> buttons = new List<CardAction>();
                CardAction button = new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show car",  value : car.id);
                buttons.Add(button);
                var heroCard = new ThumbnailCard
                {
                    Title = car.Title ?? "",
                    Subtitle = car.Model ?? "2",
                    Text = $"{car.Description}" ?? $"Text is not available for this car.",
                    Images = null,
                    Buttons = buttons
                };
                att = heroCard.ToAttachment();
                attachments.Add(att);
            }
            reply.Attachments = attachments;
            await context.Wait(AfterIDInsert);
```

AfterIDInsert call:

```
private async Task AfterIDInsert(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var carid= await result;
            await showcar(context, carid.Text);
        }
```

**Solution**
Thanks to the answer of JasonSowers I was able to find out what went wrong. Apparently MS Teams requires the CardAction to be filled in with more (all) parameters than other channels (bot emulator, for which I checked).

Using the code of JasonSowers and changing this line:

```
CardAction button = new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack,displayText:car.Title,title: "Show car", image: null, value: car.Id);
```

Solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code to try a few things and got it working with the code below.  What seemed to fix it was this line

```
CardAction button = new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show car",image : null, value: car.Id);
```

I think the properties were being read by out of order on teams or something similar, so explicitly setting `value: car.Id` seemed to fix the issue

```
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars> {
            new Cars("This is a cool car", "car1"," title1", "1"),
            new Cars("This is an awesome car", "car2", " title2", "2"),
            new Cars("This is the best car", "car3", " title3", "3"),
            new Cars("This is the worst car", "car4", " title4", "4"),
            new Cars("This is amazing", "car5"," title5", "5")
        };

        foreach (Cars car in cars)
        {

            List<CardAction> buttons = new List<CardAction>();
            CardAction button = new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show car", value: car.Id);
            buttons.Add(button);
            var heroCard = new ThumbnailCard
            {
                Title = car.Title ?? "",
                Subtitle = car.Model ?? "2",
                Text = $"{car.Description}" ?? $"Text is not available for this car.",
                Buttons = buttons
            };
            ;
            attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
        }
        reply.Attachments = attachments;
        try
        {
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

Also with this class

```
public class Cars
{
    public Cars( string description, string model, string title,  string id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
        Model = model;
        Title = title;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I all works now. The problem was the "" as parameters on the CardAction button = new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Show car", "", car.id); line. Removing that and adding value : car.id solved the problem. Thanks for your help. This seemed to be an awkward error from my side.

Comment: I was too quick... The carousel is now shown. However the value is not sent correctly. I want the id of the car to be told to context.Wait(AfterIDInsert); The result in this AfterIDInsert is now "Show car" instead of the ID of a car.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, you are saying the value of the postback is now "Show Car" instead of `car.id`?

Comment: Exactly! So somehow the parameters get screwed up. I am getting the value "Show car" (string) in my AfterIDInsert call. As where I normally would get car.id. On Skype this works, on MS Teams it doesn't. I have updated the main post with the current code.

Comment: Something working in one channel, but not another is the bane of my existence.  Why can't all channels just get along?  I'll take a look at this today.

Comment: Sorry, this fell off my radar, did you get it working?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for getting back, after solving this I didn't look back at it. So yeah! I got it working. It was the line for creating the CardAction that was still abit weird (somehow). Adding all needed parameters did the trick. Solution is added to the main post. If you add that line to your code example I will mark yours as the answer, since you brought up the right way :)